# Filtering out <script> tags, ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, filter

I am building a simple twitter copy for a school project. I am getting twits from the db with php and ajax. I have system for automatically getting new twits, and then showing a `show new twits link`. I am also using smarty template, `show_twits.php` is using the `show_twits.tpl` template. On `show_twits.tpl` there is some jquery code (that needs to be there), the problem I have, is that when there is no new twits the show more twits still appears because there is that jquery code. My question is how to filter out the response, so only the div with class 'twit' is counted in the response and not the `<script>` tags.

```
var action = "show_twits.php";
var form_data = {
    is_ajax: 1,
    automatic: 1,
    last_ID: last_ID,
    userid: userid
};
$.ajax({
      dataType : 'html',
      type: "POST",
      url: action,
      data: form_data,
      success: function(response) {

if (response != '') {   
    $('#show_new_twits').html(response);
    $('#show_new_twits_link').css('display', 'block');
} else {
    $('#show_new_twits_link').css('display', 'none');
}
}
});
```

I think the code explains what is the problem,`if (response != '')` the link is shown and the data is loaded, but that is always the case because that script tags are there, the response is never empty. Please help I tried many things with filter and find no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
success: function(response) {
    var $twits = $("<div/>").html(response).find('.twit');
    if ($twits.length) {   
      $('#show_new_twits').empty().append($twits);
      $('#show_new_twits_link').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
    $('#show_new_twits_link').css('display', 'none');
  }
}
```